# UIImage animationRepeatCounter causes image to disappear if not 0, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using an animated `UIImage`, and would like it to stop after repeating once. So logically, I use  the `animationRepeatCounter` property. However, when the property is set to anything besides 0, the image doesn't ever appear!

```
NSMutableArray * imageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:85];
for (int i = 1; i<86; i++)
{
    NSString *imagename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animation_image_%d.png", i];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imagename];
    [imageArray addObject:tempImage];
}
self.setupAnimation.animationImages = imageArray;
self.setupAnimation.animationDuration = 3.0;
self.setupAnimation.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.setupAnimation startAnimating];
}
```

If `animationRepeatCount` is set to 0, all works well (I see the image animating indefinitely). When it is set to any other number, it doesn't appear. `'self.setupAnimation'` is:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *setupAnimation;
```

Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: When is this animation started ? Are you sure the view is visible at the moment you start it ?

Comment: You're code worked fine for me.

Comment: I do believe this is the 'correct' code, as I use it elsewhere to accomplish this. I'm looking for advice on what could cause an issue like this - something to do with Interface Builder?

Comment: And yes, the view is visible, which I have confirmed since the animation works perfectly fine with animationRepeatCount = 0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm seeing the same issue, but no solutions

Comment: did you solve this, I am having the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766734/animation-not-playing-inside-speech-synthesizer-delegate?noredirect=1#comment107525325_60766734