# Animation playing or not depending on animationRepeatCount for chained animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, delegates

I am totally new to iOS and I am working on an application that has many frame animations.  Everything is going well until I try to do my final animation in a method that I am posting below.  The method is a delegate assigned to the Built in Text to Speech synthesizer

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        if spoken == 0{
            spoken += 1
            print("speaking finished")
            self.ImageView.stopAnimating()
            self.ImageView.image = self.circleImages.last
            self.ImageView.animationImages = self.circleImages
            self.ImageView.animationDuration = 1.5
            self.ImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0
            self.ImageView.startAnimating()
            do{
                try self.recordAndRecognizeSpeech()

            }catch let error{
                print(error)
            }          
        }else if spoken == 1{
                //animation 1
                spoken += 1
                            //animation 1
                self.ImageView.image = self.comingOutImages.first
                self.ImageView.animationImages = self.comingOutImages
                self.ImageView.animationDuration = 6.0
                self.ImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
                self.ImageView.startAnimating()
                print(String(self.comingOutImages.count) + " #of images")


                print("should have animated go in" + String(spoken))     
        }else{
            print("done")
        }

    }
```

The firs block of the method where spoken == 0, that animation works fine, but when it gets to the block where spoken == 1 that animation does not play it sets the image but it does not play the animation.  Ive been looking around forever, I tried to run it on the main thread and a bunch of other things.

**EDIT:**

I have this method which is the animation right before the animation above that will not play unless set animationRepeatCount to 0, and if I set this animation to anything but 0 then the animation above plays but then this animation doesn't play. In this method I have animation repeat count to 16 and then the above animation works but this one doesn't. I would like to have this animation set to repeatCount 0 and when speech is done to fire the one above to repeatCount 1. Im very new to iOS and there is something I am just not getting right.

```
func handleSend(){
        if Thread.isMainThread{
            print("send on main thread")
        }else{
            print("send not on main thread")
        }
        do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        }catch{}
        //UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, animations: {
            //animation 2
            print("second animation")
            self.imageView.stopAnimating()
            self.imageView.image = self.talkingImages.last
            self.imageView.animationImages = self.talkingImages
            self.imageView.animationDuration = 0.25
            self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 16
            self.imageView.startAnimating()
            print("should have animated")


        //})
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.finalString)
        //utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
        //utterance.rate = 0.1


        self.synthesizer.speak(utterance)

    }
```

**EDIT2: I am posting the whole viewController just for reference, and it won't let me because it exceeds the character limit, but ill post all of the animations and explain the flow**

this is the touchended override method for touching the image view, it is also where the first animation starts.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        timesRubbed += 1
        if timesRubbed == 1{
            player?.stop()
            //Toast(text: keepRubbing).show()
            self.view.makeToast(keepRubbing, duration: 3.0, position: .top)
        }
        if timesRubbed == 2{
            player?.stop()
            //Toast(text: keepAgain).show()
            self.view.makeToast(keepAgain, duration: 3.0, position: .top)
        }
        if timesRubbed == 3{
            player?.stop()
            timesRubbed += 1
            playSoundComeOut()
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                print("after animation 1")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    CATransaction.begin()
                    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{
                        print("after circle animation")
                            //UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
                                //animation 2
                                print("second animation")
                                //self.imageView.stopAnimating()
                                self.imageView.image = self.talkingImages.last
                                self.imageView.animationImages = self.talkingImages
                                self.imageView.animationDuration = 0.25
                                self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0
                                self.imageView.startAnimating()
                                print("should have animated")


                            //})
                        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.greeting)
                        //utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
                        //utterance.rate = 0.1


                        self.synthesizer.speak(utterance)
                            //CATransaction.commit()

                    }
                //UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
                    //animation 2
                    print("second animation")
                    self.imageView.stopAnimating()
                    self.imageView.image = self.circleImages.last
                    self.imageView.animationImages = self.circleImages
                    self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.5
                    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2
                    self.imageView.startAnimating()
                    print("should have animated")

                //})
                    CATransaction.commit()
                }

            }
                  //UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0, animations: {
                            //animation 1
                    if self.imageView.isFocused{
                        print("imageview is focused")
                    }else{
                        print("not focused")
                    }
                            self.imageView.image = self.comingOutImages.last
                            self.imageView.animationImages = self.comingOutImages
                            self.imageView.animationDuration = 6.0
                            self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
                            self.imageView.startAnimating()
        //                })
            CATransaction.commit()        }


    }
```

then at the end of that animation sequence it goes to the speechSynthesizer method where `spoken == 0` then it does the `handleSend()` method posted above and then it goes back to the speechSynthesizer method above where spoken == 1

If you need any more information please let me know

Comment: It doesn't look good that you use both UIView animation block and CATransaction. Try again without the UIView animation block and set your duration on the CATransaction.

Comment: no it still doesn't work, I took out the UIView animation block and put CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(6.0) before the ImageView stuff

Comment: Don't use any CATransaction stuff. You can use UIView.animate and there is a version of it that has a completion block. Also, be sure to be running your animation on the main thread like in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24985766/10058854

Comment: I tried without CATransaction and doing it on main thread and it still does not work

Comment: when I change animation repeat count to 0 it works but it repeats forever.  I am trying to only have the animation play once

Comment: in your `if spoken == 1` block, you don't call `stopAnimation()` before calling `startAnimation()` again. if you add `stopAnimation()` (like in your spoken == 0 block), does it make a difference?

Comment: @bunnyhero not it doesn't make a difference.i tried that and I just didn't post it

Comment: to be clear, the animation in spoken == 1 will not play unless I either set its repeat count to 0 or the animation before it cannot have animationrepeatcount 0, and I need the exact opposite of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this for the last animation and it worked

```
self.imageView.stopAnimating()
                self.imageView.image = self.goingInImages.last
                self.imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.contents))
                animation.values = self.goingInImages.map {$0.cgImage!}
                //animation.keyTimes = [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
                animation.calculationMode = .discrete
                animation.duration = 6.0
                animation.repeatCount = 1
                self.imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```